# Regular expression needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I want the regular expression to extract the &[1], &[2},&[3],&[4] values from the following string, with comma delimited.

```
var str = "Sum({[Account].&[1]+[Account].&[2]+[Account].&[3]+[Account].&[4]})";
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried? Is this how the string looks like when retrieved by the browser?

Comment: Yes the string looks like that when we retrieved from the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(&\[\d+\])` Seperates them in to groups, you have to delimit them with commas yourself but that's not a big problem.. :P

Btw.: This is a great test for regex testing purposes http://rubular.com/r/0kLKf1gTaD

Comment: @Termi..Thanks, but how to split like that can you please give the expression.

Comment: this isn't done with the expression. You now have one group for each `&[i]` found in the String(9 is the maximum). You can access them with `RegExp.$i` (i is a number from 1-9). Just do something like `var result = RegExp.$1 + ", " + RegExp.$2 + ", " + RegExp.$3;` or something similar. You could also use a for-loop for this.

Comment: Thats great... but how to take the numbers more than 9... Can you please tell me

Comment: Not possible as far as i know... but you could split the String if you got more than 9 of `&[i]` and test both Strings with the regex. This is just one out of more possible ways to accomplish your goal, just to be clear.. There sure is a possible way to get more than 9 values.

Comment: I found one solution to found more than 9 values is like /\d+/g this gives the how much the integer value is... :) thanks